# scala type mismatch found Future[A] expected Future[B]

Tags: scala, future

A bit new to scala, sort of confused at the type definitions here and how to resolve it.

```
  private def getContract(organizationId: String, sc: SecurityContext): Future[Contract] = {
    val configRequest = ConfigsActor.ReadConfigRequest(CONFIG_KEY, Option(organizationId))(sc)
    (configActor ? configRequest).mapTo[Config] andThen {
      case Success(config) =>
        JsonUtil.extract[Contract](config.data)
      case otherwise =>
        log.warning("some unknown case has happened", otherwise)
    }
  }
```

I would expect the akka ask to return the result, map it to a Config. In my andThen clause to convert it into a Contract type and return it.

but I get a type mismatch

```
[error] 
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[com.example.service.Config]
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[com.example.service.Contract]
[error]     (configActor ? configRequest).mapTo[Config] andThen
[error]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Future#andThen`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#andThen%5BU%5D(pf:PartialFunction%5Bscala.util.Try%5BT%5D,U%5D)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future%5BT%5D) is designed to execute a side-effect **without** transforming the value inside the future. To transform the value inside the `Future` simply map over the future

```
(configActor ? configRequest).mapTo[Config] map { config =>
  JsonUtil.extract[Contract](config.data)
} andThen { case Failure(e) => log.warning("some unknown case has happened", e) }
```

The following is worth remembering

```
someFuture
  .map     { value  => /* transform value */ }
  .recover { error  => /* transform error */ }
  .andThen {           /* execute side-effect */
    case Success(value) => logger.info("Successfully ...")
    case Failure(error) => logger.error("Failed to ...", error)
   }
```

You can think of `andThen` as [`tap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#tap%5BU%5D(f:A=%3EU):A) for `Future`s.

Comment: Oh, interesting, ok let me try that. Thank you

Comment: thank you for your answer, so if an error occurs in the future, map wouldnt be called, it would go to recover?

Comment: @Pita Yes, mapping over success is a common pattern also for other error monads such as Either, Option, Try, etc.